How to list all types of alerts using azure CLI
I am attempting to get a list of all alert rules set up for a resource group.
(Ideally, I would like to get the alert rules for an application. But I am not sure that is possible)
I have been able to get metric alerts and log search type alerts listed with these commands :
az monitor metrics alert list --resource-group 'myresourcegroup' --output table
az monitor scheduled-query list --resource-group 'myresourcegroup' --output table

In this resource group, I can also see Application Insights smart detector type alerts, but  they do not show up in either query. I cannot see in the documentation how to list alert rules for this type. Any ideas?
Thanks!

I figured out that you can do this using the azure powershell module.
Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroup" -ResourceType Microsoft.AlertsManagement/smartDetectorAlertRules | Format-Table
Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroup" -ResourceType microsoft.insights/metricAlerts | Format-Table
Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroup" -ResourceType Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules | Format-Table

